# react-native init is empty upon creation

Tags: react-native

i'm upgrading to react-native to the latest.
I'm following this https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.68/environment-setup

with current setup
ruby 2.7.5 (using rvm)
gem 3.1.6
node 14

after running this command
`npx react-native init AwesomeProject`

I only got this on my folder

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,

I just fixed it by reinstalling these

```
npm uninstall -g react-native
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli

npm install -g react-native-cli
npm install -g react-native
```